# Installing Python modules on windows

Tags: python-module

I'm trying to install [Swish-E](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Swish-E/0.5),but unfortunately a windows installer is not present so I'm trying to install it via the console (under Windows 7) but i keep on getting the same error, and i get this error on every module i try to install

```
C:\Users\Mg\Downloads\pysqlite-2.5.6\pysqlite-2.5.6>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pysqlite2._sqlite' extension
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W
3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlite2.dbapi2\" -DSQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION=
1 -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\Python26\PC /Tcsrc/module.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.6
\Release\src/module.obj
module.c
c:\users\mg\downloads\pysqlite-2.5.6\pysqlite-2.5.6\src\connection.h(
33) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or
directory
error: command '"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

I've tried installing it from `cygwin` too but that gave me the same problem.

I know it has something to do with Visual Studio's C compiler or an environment variable but I have not been able to find anything on the web.

Comment: Why are you installing pysqlite? Python 2.5 comes with sqlite3 by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At [swish-e download page](http://swish-e.org/download/index.html) there are Windows binaries.

> ### [Windows Users](http://swish-e.org/docs/install.html#windows_users)
>
> A Windows binary version is available as a separate download from the Swish-e site (http://swish-e.org). Many of the installation instructions below will not apply to Windows users; the Windows version is pre-compiled and includes libxml2, zlib, xpdf, and catdoc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have the sqlite headers. You can find them over at [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html). Anyway, why are you trying to install pysqlite?? It is included in Python 2.5 and newer.

Installers for Python 2.x can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/pysqlite/downloads/list), by the way. So you don't need to compile it yourself.

Oh, and you're trying to build sqlite instead of Swish-E if you didn't notice. Swish-E binaries are [here](http://swish-e.org/download/index.html).